# Compare a String SCSS Value

Tags: sass, mixins

I want to prevent duplicate/overwrite CSS definition.
In my example, I define a default value in the mixins headlineTypo. The font-weight is per default 700 if in the  @include headlineTypo is null.
When I declare a new CSS class (headline-medium) the $weight will set the default value, so I have :

```
.headline { font-size:12px ; font-weight: 700 }
.headline-medium { font-size:19px; font-weight: 700 }


@if ($weight != null) and (type-of($weight) == '700') {
    font-weight: $weight;
  } @else {
    font-weight: 700; // Set default
  }

@mixin headlineTypo($size: null, $weight: null) {  
  @if $size != null {
    font-size: $size;
  } @else {
    font-size: 24px; // Set default
  }

  @if ($weight != null) and ($weight != 700) {
    font-weight: $weight;
  } @else {
    font-weight: 700; // Set default
  }
}

.headline {
   @include headlineTypo(12px, null); // overwrite $size 
   &-medium {
      @include headlineTypo(19px, null); // overwrite $size
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do... why is there a `@if` on root? The first two lines are your compiled code?

Comment: `type-of($weight) == '700'` this makes no sense.